# Please make libcrypto and libssl synonyms of openssl

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a [libcrypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libcrypto) tag, which is what a program links to when linking against OpenSSL. The same can be said for the [libssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libssl) tag.

OpenSSL is covered under [openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openssl) tag, so the [libcrypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libcrypto) and [libssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libssl) tags appears to add no value and it adds some clutter.

Please make [libcrypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libcrypto) and [libssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libssl) synonyms of [openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openssl).